# ¿Es posible guardar el estado de una página en cache?

Tags: apache, symfony2, cache

Estoy haciendo un buscador de documentos en donde puedes agregar filtros, avanzar de página etc. El problema radica en que estas funcionalidades se invocan usando `AJAX`. Cuando el usuario le da a un documento del listado, la página lo redirecciona al home de dicho documento. Luego si el usuario quiere volver al buscador haciendo click en el botón de volver, los filtros aplicados y demás detalles se pierden.

Me gustaría saber si existe una forma de guardar el último estado de la página en caché y que si el usuario le da en volver se recrée la página tal y como estaba.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debido a que trabajas con AJAX lo ideal sería almacenar los parámetros de estado de la página del lado del cliente y asi poder manipularlos fácilmente con JavaScript, si no tienes problemas con eso, prosigo:

Existen varias maneras, pero recomiendo:

1. Usando **localStorage** de **Javascript**: 
   Puedes guardar los parámetros en el LocalStorage del navegador usando `localStorage.setItem('parámetro', 'valor');` y obtenerlos de nuevo con `var miParámetro= localStorage.getItem('parámetro');` estos datos son persistentes en el navegador.
2. Usando **SessionStorage** de **JavaScript**:
   La sintaxis es idéntica a la de `localStorage`, la diferencia es que los datos se pierden al cerrar el navegador. Ejemplo: `sessionStorage.setItem('parámetro', 'valor');` para guardar y `var miParámetro = sessionStorage.getItem('key');` para obtenerlos.

Pd: Puedes ver los datos guardados en el `localStorage/sessionStorage` desde Chrome en las herramientas para desarrolladores (clic derecho > inspeccionar), en la pestaña "Resources"

Comment: Creo que ese es camino. Sin embargo las interfaces de javascript que estoy usuando por ahora siguen un flujo muy rigido por lo que me es complicado capturar todos los eventos y guardarlos en la sesion del cliente.

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que puedes hacer algo manejando las sesiones del php, donde tú guardés la información de la última búsqueda en la sesión.

Algo tipo de:

`<php $_SESSION["datos_busqueda"]["primerDato"] = "valor_del_dato"; />`

Y al momento que el usuario consulta la página de las búsquedas tú recuperas tu dato

`<php echo $_SESSION["datos_busqueda"]["primerDato"]; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacerlo mediantes querys osea usando la variable GET para obtener cada opcion de los filtros, digamos tienes tus filtros echos mediante el url asi:

```
 http://www.miweb.com/?busqueda=google.com&filtro=1&filtro=2
```

Y asi sucecibamente, y crearias una link que atrape esa informacion, para que cuando le des click te regrese a la busqueda, sinperder informacion.

Espero averme explicado bien, saludos.

Comment: Aun que tambien podrias hacerlo con este metodo http://html5doctor.com/demos/history/ para que generes las paginas sin recargar, y asi no perderas lo filtros.

Comment: Usando peticiones GET para añadir los parametros y posteriormente renderizar funcionaria perfecto. El detalle es que el funcionamiento del buscador esta echo en gran parte en javascript.